# In RouteRegistrar.php line 75: Attribute [Groupe] does not exist

Tags: laravel-5.4

when i use`php artisan serve`to run my project it show me on error like this:
-->In RouteRegistrar.php line 75:
-->Attribute [Groupe] does not exist.

Comment: Show the route to the home page

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and bumped into your question via the Google-sphere.

Running `composer install` did the trick for me. I believe (at least in my case) that this error is the result of mismatched Laravel versioning vis-a-vis the routing code (I had the later version of Laravel specified in my `composer.json` but was working on an environment where I hadn't yet updated my composer packages).